# iOS app crashes when select all performed in very long UITextField

Tags: ios, crash, uitextfield

I have a `UItextField` which displays a very long string.

I tried to "Select All" (touch down on screen then select 'Select All') text in this text field and the app crashes.

In the debug view I see:

`-[NSNull dominantLanguageForScript:]:` unrecognized selector sent to `instance 0x3d571080`

I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this does not seem to be related to the amount of text in the textfield (but perhaps it is indirectly related).

It seems like you are trying to call the method `dominantLanguageForScript:` on an object.  You are expecting (I think) that that object is an instance of the NSOrthography class.  But actually, for whatever reason, it is an instance of NSNull instead.  Perhaps you are storing the instance of NSOrthography in a dictionary or array, but it is not being stored as you expect?

Comment: Thank Matthew for your comment, but I can be sure that I do not use any NSOrthography class (even I don't know what it is)